# want to store varbinary value in nvarchar datatype?

Tags: sql, nvarchar

My table `testuidpwd` have:

User:

```
Uid Password Passwordhash
----------------------------------------    
121 wrwrwr 0x0013531FA845AEA1E840BDE787336ED3CAEDFE6E
122 etetxw 0x79BAEFD23C2F4D146F9BD2FDF6C14CA25AC5D6AA
```

- `uid` `char` data type
- `password` `nvarchar(100)` data type
- `passwordhash` `nvarchar(100)` data type

My problem is when I use function `hashbytes('SHA1',password)`

```
update testdb.dbo.testuidpwd 
set pwdhash = HashBytes('SHA1', password)
```

in the column `pwdhash` is the `nvarchar(100)` data type.

When I execute the below statement

```
update testdb.dbo.testuidpwd 
set pwdhash=HashBytes('SHA1', password)
```

I got the `pwdhash` column as 硽贕ڷד瘃快ﭙ寱캏엞 this kind of format

**but I want to store the `varbinary` format......in the `pwdhash` column**

For ex:

```
update testdb.dbo.testuidpwd 
set pwdhash = cast(hashbytes('SHA1', PWD) AS varbinary)
```

this statement also doesn't work

Comment: Store `varbinary` data in `varbinary` datatype columns. `nvarchar` is not suitable for binary data.

Comment: is it possible to convert varbinary to string data type???

Comment: You could base64 encode the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simpler to store the binary value in a `varbinary` column.

That said, on SQL 2008 and later, the [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) function adds a style parameter for binary to char-type conversions (see the section "Binary Styles" of the MSDN page).

This should work (as long as you are on SQL 2008 or later):

```sql
update testdb.dbo.testuidpwd 
set pwdhash=CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),HashBytes('SHA1', password),1)
```

You can set the style to `2` instead of `1` of you want to store the value without the leading `0x`